# iOS UIButton with type UIButtonTypeRoundedRect shows a phantom button?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, ios7

We have a very simple UIButton with two background images, whenever the button is toggled on there is small rectangle shows on the up left corner of the button. This issue occurs only if the button is UIButtonTypeRoundedRect, if I switch to UIButtonTypeCustom it works fine. Does anybody have a clue?

[image: phantom button]

```
UIButton *mainBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
mainBtn.tag=0;
mainBtn.frame=CGRectMake(128, 8, 60.0, 60.0);
mainBtn.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=NO;
[mainBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_tabBar_btn_main.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[mainBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_tabBar_btn_main_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[tabBarView addSubview:mainBtn];
[mainBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(tabBarBtnTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: use UIButtonTypeCustom,it make bg as clear

Comment: So ghosts do exist...

Answer (score 2):

try this . . . .

take a custom button , and if you want to get rounded corner's then write following code

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

btn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

btn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the only reason you want to use UIButtonTypeRoundedRect in order to get the rounded corners (i.e. circle)? If so, try just using UIButtonTypeCustom, and set `mainBtn.layer.cornerRadius` to the radius you want.

Comment: I am pretty new to iOS. The only reason I want to use UIButtonTypeRoundedRect is that it provides default transformation animation when you touch it so I don't have to write extra code to implement the animation.